# Masonry stack from bottom up

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'd like to stack my Masonry bricks from the bottom up.

This question was answered before, but that modification and fork of Masonry use a very old version of the script now.  The newer version of Masonry has bug fixes which I needed.

So does anyone know how to apply the old solution to the newer script?

[Here is the old solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206376/jquery-masonry-from-bottom-up)

```
var position = (opts.fromBottom) ? {
  left: props.colW * shortCol + props.posLeft,
  bottom: minimumY
} : {
  left: props.colW * shortCol + props.posLeft,
  top: minimumY
};
```

Here is a [Fiddle with the newer Masonry script](http://jsfiddle.net/PATLZ/).  I added fromBottom option at line 74.  The code in question is around line 285.

***This question is obsolete in the newest version of Masonry (now a standard option).***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace this (starting at line 287):

```
var position = {
  top: minimumY + this.offset.y
};
```

with this:

```
var position = (this.options.fromBottom) ? {
  bottom: minimumY + this.offset.y
} : {
  top: minimumY + this.offset.y
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/GEH6n/)

Answer (score 0):

When using stack-bond it is very important to let the masonry dry before you apply a new layer. So, best is to stack line-by-line and not first up and then to the side, so you can always control the level of the total stack. Interleaving stack bond with a layer of running bond now and then is good practice and decorative too.