# Masonry js v4 from bottom up

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'd like to stack my Masonry tiles from bottom up using Masonry v4.2.0

The old solution is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539368/masonry-stack-from-bottom-up). But it used an older version so code structure is different now from that one.

So does anyone know how to apply the old solution to the newer script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loot at the documentation https://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html

There is a setting called originTop, should be what you need.